# AWS DynamoDB - converter class - "Bad request, unable to parse JSON"

Tags: java, json, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've made a generic method that is convertor class for complex classes and 2nd one for enums. I have Recipe class that is complex so I used @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ObjectConverter.class)

This is my converter class:

```
public class ObjectConverter<T extends Object> implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, T> {

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public String convert(T object) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse JSON");
}

@Override
public T unconvert(String object) {
    try {
        T unconvertedObject = objectMapper.readValue(object, new TypeReference<T>() {
        });
        return unconvertedObject;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is convertor class for enums:

```
public class EnumConverter<T extends Object> implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, List<T>> {

@Override
public String convert(List<T> objects) {
    //Jackson object mapper
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String objectsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objects);
        return objectsString;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        //do something
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<T> unconvert(String objectsString) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        List<T> objects = objectMapper.readValue(objectsString, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {
        });
        return objects;
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        //do something
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        //do something
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do something
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is when I try to test CRUDs methods.. I have addProduct method and this one works fine, I created addRecipe method and it looks almost the same, but here I have problem while posting in Postman i got an error: "Bad request, unable to parse JSON".

And information from log file:

> "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: {"id":null,"name":"test","labels":["GLUTEN_FREE"],"author":{"name":"Plejer Annołn","id":"testID2"},"media":{"name":"heheszki","url":"http://blabla.pl","mediaType":"IMAGE"},"recipeElements":{"product":{"id":927c3ed3-400b-433d-9da0-1aa111dce584,"name":"bąkiKacpraNieŚmierdzą","calories":1000,"fat":400.0,"carbo":20.0,"protein":40.0,"productKinds":["MEAT"],"author":{"name":"Plejer Annołn","id":"testID2"},"media":{"name":"heheszki","url":"http://blabla.pl","mediaType":"IMAGE"},"approved":false},"weight":"100"},"approved":false}; line: 1, column: 190] (through reference chain: pl.javamill.model.kitchen.Recipe["recipeElements"])"

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The methods in the converter class are always returning a value even if exceptions are thrown (unless they are RuntimeExceptions), though they may not be correctly marshaling/unmarshaling the `Product` in `RecipeElement`. A better alternative is to annotate the `getRecipeElement()` method in your class with [`@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson.html), that provides out-of-the-box JSON marshaling/unmarshaling. It may be something to do with the HTTP request you are sending in Postman too. You should add more information on the `getProduct()`, `setProduct()` methods and the actual postman request (without any sensitive information).

Comment: I changed some things and now in log file i have this information: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token" in recipeElement

Comment: @D.Zet I suspect this must be for some old data. What are the contents of the class where this object is used?

Comment: Hey I edited my question, please check it for more details